# Error - System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

Tags: apex, webservices

An existing integration from Salesforce to Oracle stopped working this morning. When I send an http request from Salesforce to an Oracle webservice, I get a message "System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac". This seems like a common Java related error related to SSL and there are some suggested fixes on the web. However, I do not find any reference to this error in the context of Salesforce.

Has anyone seen this error in Salesforce? What was the issue and how did you resolve this?

Comment: This might not be a Salesforce issue, maybe the other server changed? Did it make config/code changes due to Heartbleed or an unrelated software update? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154617/how-to-troubleshoot-ssl-bad-record-mac-exception

Comment: Thanks John. That is what I suspect. A lot of other sources also point to SSL/Certificate issues on the other server. But it is difficult to pinpoint the cause. I will ppost an update wtih the issue cause/resolution once it is resolved

Comment: Any solutions found for this? It seems like APEX callout is having issues with our server's SSLv3. Trying to instruct our server to use TLSv1 instead but not sure yet if this will help. The strange thing is that this error occurred very seldom but today we've experienced it many times. Some changes are definitely happening on Salesforce instances.

Comment: We're hitting this intermittently as well and as I'm sure each of you know, the Salesforce specific results that come up after Googling are very few in number. Have you guys had any luck since posting or come across any additional information?

Comment: If this is still the case, did you already had salesforce support take a look ?

Comment: Yeah, I've had multiple attempts; unfortunately each getting pre-maturely closed due to the reviewer labeling it as a code support/review case for premier support (don't have).

Answer (score 2):

In November and December 2014 Salesforce will be disabling SSL 3.0 encryption in stages to prevent it from being used to access the Salesforce platform.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-disabling-SSL-3-0-encryption&language=en_US