# System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac in calling External URL

Tags: apex, exception

I am having the below error for calling out the external web URL which is supposed to be accessed by public at all time.

```
System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
```

I found that the error happens at random and sometimes only. But now it starts to happen more frequently.

I googled it and couldn't find any specific solution.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: If it is [this openssl issue](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39844/getting-ssl-alert-write-fatal-bad-record-mac-during-openssl-handshake) then the problem is most likely in either the external service or in the Salesforce platform rather than your Apex code.

Comment: Similar: [Error - System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33275/error-system-calloutexception-received-fatal-alert-bad-record-mac/34409)