# Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest

When performing callouts from Salesforce to various remote endpoints, we'll occassionally/intermittently receive a "bad_record_mac" error.  Sometimes they are persistent and don't go away after a period of time, othertimes the next callout works without a problem.

Doing some Googling, it doesn't see to be an uncommon issue in the Java world, but the resources that are more Salesforce centric are very few in number.  Those resources revolve around enabling or limiting various forms of SSL on the server (SSLv3, TLSv1, etc), but there's not a lot of information around the cause and as you imagine, no difinitive solution or response from Salesforce about it.

Does anyone successfully debugged these issues or have more information about why these Salesforce originating responses are dropping at the endpoint?

Thanks in advance!

Hoping to get to the bottom of this and ultimately have more information available to other users that experience this in the future.  Also posted in the SF Dev Community:  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AkM6IAK

Note:  This was marked as a duplicate of:  [Error - System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33275/error-system-calloutexception-received-fatal-alert-bad-record-mac).  That post did not have a response - I was requested to start a new question.

Comment: That post did not have a response and when I responded to it, I was told to open a new case.  What's the solution here?  I feel like I'm jumping through more hoops just to bring more awareness to the issue.

Comment: If updating your old question with more information does not help, it is unlikely that any new question will result in answers. Know that any update equally puts your question back on the first page.

Comment: Clarification - it wasn't my old question, it was one that seems to have abandoned.  When trying to utilize it, I was told to create a new one.